# Moving background windows on Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos, mac

Is there anyway to move background windows without bringing them to the front?

**Links**

- According to [this thread](http://maketecheasier.com/mac-keeping-your-application-window-%E2%80%98always-on-top%E2%80%99/2008/07/09), using <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd> allows you to move background windows without bringing them to the front. I haven't been able to replicate this on Mac OS X 10.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only <kbd>Command</kbd> (sometimes referred to as the Apple key) you need to be holding. If you hold any other modifier keys it will be as if you clicked on the window. Additionally it only works on the title bar, scroll bar and the resize corner.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the ability to insert keys. It is pretty cool.

Comment: Note that on Xcode this doesn't seem to work if you click on the actual title